# Need an array where with first element of new array=sum of all elements except the first element-Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, except

I have an array arr[0,1,2,3,..10] in Java script.I need to make a new array with first element of new array=sum of all elements except the first element of the previous array,and goes on.

**Description:** I have

```
  Array=new Arr[0,1,2,3,..10].
```

I need an

```
  Array=new new Array[first element,second element..]
```

where

```
 first element=(1+2+..10)-0 ,
    second element=(0+2+3+..10)-1,
    third element=(0+1+3+..10)-2,

.. goes on till last element.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var sum = myArray.reduce(function(previous, current) {
    return previous + current;
}, 0);
var newArray = myArray.map(function(currentElement) {
    return sum - currentElement;
});
console.log(newArray);
```

**Output**

```
[ 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45 ]
```

Comment: Although OP has not mentioned whether he wants it to work on older IE versions or not. If he wants to support <= IE8, then he has to do polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm goes like this

1. Just calculate the sum of all elements in the array
2. Traverse the array and reduce the element value from the sum and push into new array

### Code

```
var sum = 0;
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  sum += arr[i];
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result.push(sum - arr[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

**Note** that, this can be done with short snippets of code as well using a combination of Array.reduce and Array.every, Array.slice. But these all methods have browser compatibility issues as they are not supported in older IE browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll have to do something like this:

```
var nums = new Array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
var sum = Function('return ' + nums.join('+') + ';')();
var final = [];

for(j = 0; j < nums.length; j++){
   final.push(sum - (2 * nums[j]) );
}

console.log(final);
```

The reason you have to do `(2 * nums[i])` in the last step is:

1. To get rid of the item from the original addition (the 2 in the line below - from your code),
2. To subtract it at the end of the line.

> var third element=(0+1+3+..10)-2,

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5p56x/2/)
- Cred to @wared for the sum function -

Comment: +1 It seems to be quite close to asker's requirements. Here a quick way to add up all elements : `var sum = Function('return ' + nums.join('+') + ';')();`.

Comment: Nice, I've never seen that before! I hope it's okay I incorporated that into my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

//Sum them all
sum = 0
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   sum+=arr[i];
}

//Calculate the result
result = []
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   result.push(sum-arr[i]);
}

alert(result);
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eg7F6/

Answer (score 0):

This is the generic approach:

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var sum = array.reduce(function (sum, value) { return sum+= value });
var newArray = array.map(function(value) { return sum - value });
```

However, if the array has always values from 0 to 10, you could do some shortcut – but at this point, I do not understand the point of having that.

Comment: Idential to @thefourtheye's answer. Please check before posting